# how to add sbteclipse plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbteclipse

I am using sbt 0.13 and I would like to add sbteclipse plugin so that eclipse import my sbt project  and I can write my scala code easily. While searching on the internet I got [this](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) link. I read all the instruction that to make plugins.sbt file and added plugin in it but I am confused about what to download and after downloading this zip file what should I do next please.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to download anything by hand. Just follow the instructions for sbt 0.13 and higher.

Add this to your plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")
```

Start the sbt shell and type eclipse.

This automaticly downloads the plugin and creates the eclipse project files for you.

Now you can just import the project via the import project wizard in eclipse.

You can find this instructions at the README file on github:
https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2):

eclipse doesn't have sbt plugin

although sbt has an eclipse plugin

which is a workaround but not proper solution.

which means **eclipse doesnt understand build.sbt as it does for pom.xml or build.gradle**
so if we change a dependency in our eclipse project in build.sbt file, eclipse will not understand it, and will not change the dependency in the project dependencies.So you have to do the below steps everytime u modify any dependency.

The workaround is as follows

**Step1:** Download and install sbt from https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Setup.html
        for windows it is pretty straight forward  https://piccolo.link/sbt-1.2.8.msi pretty straight forward

**Step2:** Create a folder say D:\sbt\edge
        now create a build.sbt file here
        You can use the following as the content, change it accordingly

```
name := "edge"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
val sparkVersion="2.4.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion % "runtime",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % sparkVersion % Test,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-repl" % sparkVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-yarn" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib-local" % sparkVersion,
//"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.6.3",
//"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.6.3",
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3"
)
```

now create these nested folders src and main like -> D:\sbt\spark\src\main

**Step3:** Open CMD/PowerShell go to D:\sbt\edge 
            run "sbt package"

**Step4:** Go inside .sbt in ur home directory and in plugins folder of the correct version in my case C:\Users\xxxx.sbt\1.0\plugins
            if u have a plugins.sbt file already, add the following line **addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")**
            if not, create and add the line.

**Step5:** Go back to CMD/PowerShell , run  sbt eclipse. It will create the necessary files for eclipse project.
**Step6:** Open an eclipse workspace, and import this project as an existing project.

Answer (score 1):

To create Eclipse Project defination, include the plugin dependency in PROJECT_DIR/project/plugins.sbt.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.1.0")
```

Add sources & Javadoc jars in your build.sbt

```
EclipseKeys.withSource := true
EclipseKeys.withJavadoc := true
```

In Intellij just use Intellij Scala plugin
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have followed below steps for installing sbt on my windows machine

1. downloaded and extracted sbt zip
2. set path in environment variable
3. ran **sbt** int cmd (it did take sometime to download some dependencies)

   On windows OS you will find the sbt folder in your user profile folder under **C:\Users\UserName.sbt\1.0**
4. If plugins folder is not present in above directory then you can create one and also create plugins.sbt file in this new folder(C:\Users\UserName.sbt\1.0\plugins)
5. add below command/text in plugins.sbt and save it
   **addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")**
6. now when you run **sbt** command on cmd you can type >**eclipse** so that it gets auto downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse SBT for MAC /IOS

1. Go to your SBT project
2. go to  directory and then inside it go to project folder like

> PROJECT_DIR/project/

3. now find `plugins.sbt` named file and add this below line

   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")
4. Start the sbt shell `> sbt` and then type > `eclipse`
5. This automatically downloads the plugin and creates the eclipse project files for you and import this project as existing project to your eclipse